# AWS SAM, AWS Lambda, UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 66: invalid start byte

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, machine-learning, aws-lambda

I followed the example of ([Serverless Deployment of ML models on AWS Lambda](https://towardsdatascience.com/serverless-deployment-of-machine-learning-models-on-aws-lambda-5bd1ca9b5c42)) and had no problems with running the code locally and on AWS.
I tried to adjust the original example for Fastai model. However, after `sam local start-api` and running the testing code in the local Jupyter notebook, I get the error.
The change I made was:

```
loc_fastai = torch.load('test-fastai-project.pth')
```

instead of

```
knnclf = joblib.load('knnclf.joblib')
```

The error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 55, in main
    add_default_site_directories()
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 42, in add_default_site_directories
    site.addsitedir(os.environ["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 164, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 66: invalid start byte
27 Nov 2022 10:55:04,361 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 1 InvokeID=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 55, in main
    add_default_site_directories()
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 42, in add_default_site_directories
    site.addsitedir(os.environ["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 164, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 66: invalid start byte
END RequestId:
```

Obviously, the code does not reach `lambda_predict.py`. I tried to remove that code and return to the example [1](https://towardsdatascience.com/serverless-deployment-of-machine-learning-models-on-aws-lambda-5bd1ca9b5c42), but without success. I get the error continuously. I tried removing the images, also without success. I noticed only removing the images, restarting the docker (Docker for Windows), and creating a new project. However, repeating the code for reading the fastai model gives the error again.
I also tried putting in the docker file:

```
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_US:en \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

After the error, I guess the state is cashed, but I don't know where to look.
How to solve this problem?